# debug a function when Safely from Purrr has been used?

Tags: r, purrr

I have a function that has been saved as an Rds object and I'm wondering if there is any possibility **after** reading the function to `debug()` it or to see the code inside the function?

Example

```
library(purrr)

some_function <- function(x){


  avg <- mean(x)
  std <- sd(x)

  return(c(avg, std))

} 

safe_function <- safely(some_function)

saveRDS(safe_function, 'safe_function.rds')
rm(safe_function)

# How can I debug the function or make changes to it after I've loaded it?

safe_function <- readRDS('safe_function.rds')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

1. Execute `debug(safe_function)` in the console and then call your function, say, `safe_function(c(1, 2))`
2. At this time, you will be in debug mode:
   [image]
3. In your console, execute `debugonce(.f)` and then hit either 'next' or 'continue' (alternatively, type `n` or `c` in the console)
4. You will now be within the body of your `some_function` and will be able to see the code:
   [image]

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that it's easy to extract the underlying function, with a single line of code:

```r
extracted_function <- environment(safe_function)$.f

extracted_function
#> function(x){
#> 
#> 
#>   avg <- mean(x)
#>   std <- sd(x)
#> 
#>   return(c(avg, std))
#> 
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x1951c3e0>
```

You can debug this function however you like, then if you want to overwrite it but keep it within its `safely` wrapper, you can overwrite it like this:

```
debugged_function <- function(x) c(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))

environment(safe_function)$.f <- debugged_function

safe_function(1:10)
#> $result
#> [1] 5.50000 3.02765
#>
#> $error
#> NULL
```

---

I'll give a quick explanation of why this works:

If you examine your `safe_function`, you will notice a couple of unusual things about it. Although you have loaded it into the global environment, it is actually wrapped in its own unnamed environment (in this case `<environment: 0x095704c0>`), which is integral to the way that it works:

```r
safe_function
#> function (...) 
#> capture_error(.f(...), otherwise, quiet)
#> <bytecode: 0x0956fd50>
#> <environment: 0x095704c0>
```

The other odd thing you'll notice is that `safe_function` calls the function `.f`, which is neither a built-in function, nor a function exported from `purrr`. That's because `.f` is a copy of your original function that is kept inside this special environment.

We can look at the complete contents of the unnamed environment by doing:

```
ls(environment(safe_function), all.names = TRUE)
#> [1] ".f"        "otherwise" "quiet"
```

Now, if you look at what `.f` is, you will find it is just a copy of your original `some_function`:

```
#> function(x){
#> 
#> 
#>   avg <- mean(x)
#>   std <- sd(x)
#> 
#>   return(c(avg, std))
#> 
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x1951c3e0>
```

So this is where your wrapped function is "hiding". It remains accessible as a member of this unnamed environment, which can be accessed via `environment(safe_function)` so is easy to modify if desired.